# Magento 2 depends tag on multiselect values on system.xml

Tags: magento, magento2

here's my first question to stackoverflow community after years.

I have a custom module written for Magento 2, on system.xml I have to show a field if first multiselect option is selected, I have to show the second field if second multiselect option is selected. If both multiselect options are selected I have to show both dependant fields.

I hope I've explained well, here's the code I wrote (the relevant part):

```
<field id="master_field" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="400" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Master field</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Field\Value</source_model>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
</field>

<field id="dependant_field_1" translate="label" sortOrder="410" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Dependant field 1</label>
    <depends>
        <field id="master_field">One</field>
    </depends>
</field>

<field id="dependant_field_2" translate="label" sortOrder="420" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Dependant field 2</label>
    <depends>
        <field id="master_field">Two</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for coming to stackoverflow. I worked as a magento 1 dev for years and the one thing I learned (about stackoverflow) is to post the entire module if you really want help. Its really hard to decide whats relevant so including all related custom code will attract more attention and analysis to your problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your suggestion. I would love to add the entire module but I can't because of agency's policy.
To clarify my question, the dependant field works well if depends to a select. It fails to work when depends to a multiselect only when multiple choices were opted in.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?